# playbackStoreID for an MPMediaItem is coming 0 (working with apple music). In which condition it happens?

Tags: ios, iphone

playbackStoreID for an MPMediaItem is coming 0 (Working with Apple Music). In which condition it happens ?

Comment: Have you solved it?